# Laravel 5 Eloquent - query for absense of relationship in model - e.g. retrieve user's unanswered questions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have `User`, `Answer`, and `Question` models. Answers belong to users and questions, i.e. the `answers` table has a `user_id` column and a `question_id` column.

My `User` model has a method to return all answered questions

```
class User extends Model {
    public function answeredQuestions(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Answer', 'App\Question');
    }
}
```

I'd like to have another method to retrieve all unanswered questions, but I'm not sure how to go about that. As a workaround I can get it from the `Question` model by passing in a user id like this:

```
class Question extends Model {
    public function scopeUnanswered($query, $user_id){
        return $query->whereDoesntHave('answers', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
        });
    }
}
```

I would prefer to access it via the `User` model with `$user->unansweredQuestions` though. Is this possible to do cleanly through the User model?

Comment: Why are you do the Query in Model why don't you use a controller...I am new to laravel,,that's why i need to know...Model is more like a reference to the table isn't it...?

Comment: @SalindaKrish Laravel suggests creating fat models and skinny controllers - i.e. put the bulk of data transformation work in your model where possible to keep your controllers as clean as possible. I still have a controller, but a model should handle all the query work and the controller just handles the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brother

Comment: Yes brother @Mathew i got the point... Thanks

Comment: @Matthew can you describe the relation between User and Question ?